# Mongodb user is not stored

Tags: mongodb

I have an issue with MongoDB
I try to create a new user for a new db that I just created but it seems like the new user is not saved. When I switch from the new database to the admin the user just disappears

I got this with mongosh :

```
use MernProject
db.createUser({ user : "mernUser", pwd: "*********" , roles: ["readWrite", "dbAdmin"]})
{
  ok: 1,
  '$clusterTime': {
    clusterTime: Timestamp({ t: 1640082039, i: 1 }),
    signature: {
      hash: Binary(Buffer.from("94437807c4ebc7bc420349099d29cdd38362c281", "hex"), 0),
      keyId: Long("7043903325019832326")
    }
  },
  operationTime: Timestamp({ t: 1640082039, i: 1 })
}
db.getUsers()
{
  users: [
    {
      _id: 'MernProject.mernUser',
      userId: UUID("ff4cd710-a5a1-43b2-89bb-f65e90f69a46"),
      user: 'mernUser',
      db: 'MernProject',
      roles: [
        { role: 'readWrite', db: 'MernProject' },
        { role: 'dbAdmin', db: 'MernProject' }
      ],
      mechanisms: [ 'SCRAM-SHA-1', 'SCRAM-SHA-256' ]
    }
  ],
  ok: 1,
  '$clusterTime': {
    clusterTime: Timestamp({ t: 1640082039, i: 1 }),
    signature: {
      hash: Binary(Buffer.from("94437807c4ebc7bc420349099d29cdd38362c281", "hex"), 0),
      keyId: Long("7043903325019832326")
    }
  },
  operationTime: Timestamp({ t: 1640082039, i: 1 })
}
use admin
switched to db admin
use MernProject
switched to db MernProject
db.getUsers()
{
  users: [],
  ok: 1,
  '$clusterTime': {
    clusterTime: Timestamp({ t: 1640082066, i: 1 }),
    signature: {
      hash: Binary(Buffer.from("f6cc7f1d49775311fd6983c928b7f37b581b8af8", "hex"), 0),
      keyId: Long("7043903325019832326")
    }
  },
  operationTime: Timestamp({ t: 1640082066, i: 1 })
}
```

Do I miss something ?

Comment: The problem seems to come from the managed Mongodb of OVH it's working with a local instance of mongoDB